# IntegrityError at /users/signup NOT NULL constraint failed: users_user.username

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

## What I was doing

I was making the signup form with using ModelForm in forms.py and FormView in views.py. I am making users to use their email as their username when they are logging in so that they can easily set new passwords if they lost.

## Error Image

It just threw `IntegrityError` in my console.

[IntegrityError at / NOT NULL contraint failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Btyat.png)

## What I have tried to solve issue

1. I deleted all the migration files and db file so that there won't be any duplicated users in my database. And then I created new superuser and then created new user.
2. I got rid of `email` field in `fields` in `Meta` class and then created cleaning method of email (`def clean_email(self):`). However this solution didn't work obviously because it will delete the email field in my signup form.

## Source code

Below are my all source codes that might be related to this topic.

1. templates/users/signup.html

```
{% block content %}
    <section id="signup">
        <form method="POST", action="{% url 'users:signup' %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <button type="submit">Signup</button>
        </form>
    </section>
{% endblock content %}
```

2. users/forms.py

```py
class SignupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email']

    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, label='Confirm Password')

    # Validating password 
    def clean_confirm_password(self):
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        confirm_password = self.cleaned_data.get('confirm_password')
        if password != confirm_password:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Password should be matched!')
        else: 
            return password 

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user.username = username
        user.set_password = password 
        user.save()
```

3. users/view.py

```py
class SingupView(FormView):
    template_name = 'users/signup.html'
    form_class = forms.SignupForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('common:home')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(self.request, username=email, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(self.request, user)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

My github repo is https://github.com/donghhan/knowner-website.git

Please give me a help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error says that you didnt add username as data
in your SignupForm you excluded that field, hence the error, either

1. add it to form

   fields = ['username','first_name', 'last_name', 'email']

or

2. modify User model, in a way that username is not required, you cant just pass email as username, you need to remodel the Model, something like:

## inherit from AbstractBaseUser and adjust

```
class NewUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

  email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
  #username = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
  start_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
  is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

  objects = CustomManager()

  USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
  REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name','last_name'] # or as you decide

  def __str__(self):
      return self.email # or what you choose
```

## add new manger of the new user model eith some validation

```
class CustomManager(BaseUserManager):

def create_superuser(self, email, username, first_name, password, **other_fields):

    other_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
    other_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
    other_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

    if other_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
        raise ValueError(
            'Superuser must be assigned to is_staff=True.')
    if other_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
        raise ValueError(
            'Superuser must be assigned to is_superuser=True.')

    return self.create_user(email, username, first_name, password, **other_fields)

def create_user(self, email, username, first_name, password, **other_fields):

    if not email:
        raise ValueError(_('You must provide an email address'))

    email = self.normalize_email(email)
    user = self.model(email=email, username=username,
                      first_name=first_name, **other_fields)
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save()
    return user
```

lastly add in settings:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "users.NewUser"
```

you could look up explicit details in the django officeil docs

Comment: I would still want to make users to login with their email, not username. In this case, if I am re-modeling the Model, then should I give up using AbstractUser in this case?

Comment: i've just added that to the answer, hope that what you're looking for

Comment: Thank you. But I just ended up making username set to be email address in both views and forms. However, I would definitely remember your solutions!